# Libgdx shader, render and draw confusion

Tags: opengl, libgdx, shader, render, draw

in my Libgdx Scene2D stage I am trying to have an actor flashing with white color.
With OpenGLES 2.0 I understood I needed to use a shader to achieve this and I have a problem implementing it.

My goal is to color an actor in solid white color given a speficic game event. The problem is given this specific event, everything in the stage becomes white (all actors and the background) instead of just the selected actors textures.

My World class is where the stage is created. It is rendered like this:

```
public void render() {
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
update();
stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
stage.draw();
}
```

In the stage I use actors that are defined in a MyActor class. This class has its own 
draw method where I am trying to color the actor in solid white with the shader. Here is the draw method:

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha) {
    if (flashing) {
        batch.setShader(shader);            
    }

    batch.flush();

    Color color = getColor();
    batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * alpha);

    batch.draw(tr, getX(), getY(), side/2, side/2, side, side, getScaleX(), getScaleY(), 0);        
}
```

Obviously I do something wrong with the batch. Instead of coloring this one actor in white, it colors everything. Also it remains white even after the Boolean flashing = false;

Here is how I have set up my shader, in the actor class MyActor:

```
ShaderProgram shader;
String vertexShader =
        "attribute vec4 a_position; \n" +
        "attribute vec4 a_color;\n" +
        "attribute vec2 a_texCoord0; \n" +
        "uniform mat4 u_projTrans; \n" +
        "varying vec4 v_color; \n" +
        "varying vec2 v_texCoords; \n" +
        "void main() { \n" +
        "v_color = a_color; \n" +
        "v_texCoords = a_texCoord0; \n" +
        "gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position; \n" +
        "};";

String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n" +
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "#endif\n" + "varying vec4 v_color;\n" +
        "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n" +
        "uniform float grayscale;\n" +
        "void main()\n" +
        "{\n" +
        "vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);\n" +
        "float gray = dot(texColor.rgb, vec3(5, 5, 5));\n" +
        "texColor.rgb = mix(vec3(gray), texColor.rgb, grayscale);\n" +
        " gl_FragColor = v_color * texColor;\n" +
        "}";
```

Then initiated with:

```
shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

I have to admit I probably don't understand correctly how the batch of MyActor, the drawing method and the rendering methods work together!

Thanks for your time

Comment: Do you reset the `Shader` somewhere, so that `SpriteBatch` uses the defaukt `Shader` again? Actually in your case i would not do it with a `Shader`, this task is not that complex. Just store the default `Texture` and a solid white `Texture` and say `Texture t = flashing ? white : default;` and the `draw` the `Texture t`.

Comment: Hey @Springrbua, thanks for your answer. No I don't think I reset the shader anywhere, how can I do that? I would rather avoid using a second set of white textures manually created, there is supposed to be dozens of different textures in my game, each with a unique shape, so the programmatic approach looks way better I think

Comment: You could and should use `TextureAtlas` anyways, but you have to decide. I think if you say `batch.setShader(null)` it uses the default `Shader` again, but i am not sure.

Comment: The javadok of the `setShader` says: "Call this method with a null argument to use the default shader. "

Comment: brilliant, that works, thanks. IF you want to write it as an answer I can approve it for you :)
I already use a TextureAtlas but unless I didn't get you, I don't want to manually create png files of dozen of sprites with white solid color. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is, that you never set the `Shader` back to the default `Shader`, so your `Spritebatch` always uses the "solid white" `Shader`. 
As the javadock of the `setShader(ShaderProgram shader)`sais you can reset the `Shader` by calling `setShader(null)`.
Another possibility would be to use another `Texture` for the solid white and the simply say:

```
Texture t = flashing ? whiteTexture : defaultTexture;
```

and `draw` the `Texture t`.
Just a suggestion: Do not use `batch.flush()` if it is not absolutely neccessary, because `flush()` makes a draw call to the GPU and this costs some performance.

Comment: thanks a lot, not only your answer is correct but you also too k the time for discussion beforehands. You also have good suggestions. Have a nice day